# Angular5: How to bind ngClass to a property in an array?

Tags: angular

HTML:

```
<select name="title" [(ngModel)]="person.title">
<select name="name" [(ngModel)]="person.name">
<select name="address" [(ngModel)]="person.address">
<select name="age" [(ngModel)]="person.age">
```

Component:

```
public person: Person;
public errors: = [{property:"name", message:"Name contains invalid characters"},{property:"age", message:"Age must be greater than 18"}];
```

I have a form with four properties. When the submit button is clicked, if there are validation errors it will go into the errors array. If there are no errors than the array will be empty.

I want to add an "error" css class to the input tags that have a validation error (so it can put red borders around it). Everytime the submit button is pressed the error list in the component will get updated.

I've tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```
<input name="age" [ngClass]="{'error': errors.findIndex(x => x.property=='age') !== -1 }" [(ngModel)]="person.age">
```

Does anyone know how I can bind the ngClass on the input fields to a property in the array? (I need a solution that keeps this array).

Comment: When you update the form arrays why don't you check the property and append the error class you the relevant input

Comment: suggest to try out inbuild method find and hasOwnProperty  , easy to use and understand , given same in answer

Comment: @Lasithds how would i append the error class to the relevant input?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like :

```
[ngClass]="{'error': errors.findIndex(function(x){ return x.property == 'age'}) !== -1 }"
```

> Note : Instead of using findIndex on template side , create a
>   function on component side for this and call that.

---

**Template Side :**

```
[ngClass]="{'error': isError('age') }"
```

**Component Side :**

```
isError(name){
    return this.errors.findIndex(x => x.property == name ) !== -1
}
```

---

Comment: We can also use `Array.prototype.some` method instead of `findIndex`

Comment: Actually that was a typo from copy/paste, fixed it. Your solution only works first time though. Everytime the list of error gets updated I need the class to get updated as well.

Comment: @FruitDealer , will you please check updated answer ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi Your solution only works once when the component is loaded. I need the classes to change when the list of errors is updated. So i don't think i can use a function because I need it to bind with the component property.

Comment: @FruitDealer , I have update the first solution , calling function was second solution please check second line with code in my answer and please check

Answer (score 0):

You can use getter in this case as:

**HTML**

```
<input name="age" [ngClass]="{'error': isError}" [(ngModel)]="person.age">
```

then in your component use getter like:

**Component**

```
get isError() {
  return this.errors.findIndex(x => x.property=='age') !== -1;
}
```

**Other solution**

maintain your errors in Object like:

```
errors = {
   age: "<message>",
   name: "<message>"
}
```

In your HTML bind with property directly like:

```
<input name="age" [ngClass]="{'error': errors.age != undefined}" [(ngModel)]="person.age">
```

Comment: Problem with using a function is that the class won't update when the list of errors update. When the list of errors get updated I need the classes to automatically update as well (because the user will constantly press the submit button)

Comment: it's not normal function it's getter so try with it, I'm sure it will work

Comment: @FruitDealer I have updated answer with one more possible solution you can try it as well.

Comment: @FruitDealer any luck?

Answer (score 0):

try like this , make use of [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) that will do

```
error.find( ele => return ele.hasOwnProperty('age') );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is valide expression, but first thing I will try i will be wraping this function in function in component. Next I will pass a property name and return ture if it find it:

```
 errorTest(prop) {
  return test=  this.error.findIndex(x => x.property == prop) > -1;      
}
```

In class check, I will use this function

Comment: Problem with using a function is that the class won't update when the list of errors update. When the list of errors get updated I need the classes to automatically update as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add class and errors to relevant inputs on submit function. Here's a working example

```js
let errors = [{property:"name", message:"Name contains invalid characters"},{property:"age", message:"Age must be greater than 18"}];
    
// on submit function
for(let i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
  let el = document.querySelector("#myform select[name="+ errors[i].property +"]");
  el.classList.add('error');
}
```

```css
.error{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">
    <select name="title" [(ngModel)]="person.title"></select>
    <select name="name" [(ngModel)]="person.name"></select>
    <select name="address" [(ngModel)]="person.address"></select>
    <select name="age" [(ngModel)]="person.age"></select>
  </form>
```